# c++ program crashing. Not sure why

Tags: c++, vector

**Your Community Supported Agriculture (CSA) farm delivers a box of fresh fruits and vegetables to your house once a week. For this programming project, define the class BoxOfProduce that contains exactly three bundles of fruits or vegetables. You can represent the fruits or vegetables as an array of type string. Add appropriate constructors and accessor/mutator functions to get or set the fruits or vegetables stored in the array. Also write an output
function that displays the complete contents of the box on the console.
Next, write a main function that creates a BoxOfProduce with three items randomly selected from this list:**

**• Broccoli
• Tomato
• Kiwi
• Kale
• Tomatillo**

**Do not worry if your program randomly selects duplicate produce for the three items. Next, the main function should display the contents of the box and allow the user to substitute any one of the five possible fruits or vegetables for any of the fruits or vegetables selected for the box. After the user is done with substitutions it should output the final contents of the box to be delivered. Then it should ask if the user wants to create another box and if
yes, it should repeat the above steps. It should keep doing so until the user chooses not to create another box of produce.
Finally, add a static variable to your class that keeps track of the total number of boxes of produce created and a static function that returns that value. Display this value in the main function at the end of each iteration of the main loop.**

My program gets to the removeStuff() function after the user types Y if they want to swap out the bundle. Once it gets there and the user types what fruit/vegetable they want to remove, the program shuts down. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BoxOfProduce.h"
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char myChar;
string answer = "";

srand(time(0));

BoxOfProduce bo;
bo.randomize();

cout << "Your box initially starts with: " << endl;
cout << bo.random << endl;

vector<string> randomResult = bo.randomize();
for (vector<string>::const_iterator iter = randomResult.begin(), iterEnd = randomResult.end();
        iter != iterEnd; ++iter){
    cout << *iter << endl;
    }

cout << "Would you like to swap out any of your bundles for any of the five     bundles you didn't get? (Y/n) " << endl;
    getline(cin, answer);
    if(answer.length() == 1){
        myChar = answer[0];
    }
    if(myChar == 'y' || myChar == 'Y'){
        cout << "Okay!" << endl;
        bo.removeStuff();
    }else if(myChar == 'n' || myChar == 'N'){
        BoxOfProduce bo1;
        bo1.createBox();
    }else{
        cout << "That is not a valid character. Goodbye." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

}

---------------------------------------------------------------------

#include "BoxOfProduce.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

BoxOfProduce::BoxOfProduce()
{
}

vector<string> BoxOfProduce::randomize()
{
    srand(time(0));
    string choices[] = {"Broccoli", "Tomato", "Kiwi", "Kale", "Tomatillo"};

    vector<string> random;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        random.push_back(choices[rand() % 5]);
    }
    return random;
}

vector<string> BoxOfProduce::printContents(vector<string> bundles[3])
{
    cout << "Your box contains these three bundles: " << endl;
    cout << bundles << endl;
}

void BoxOfProduce::createBox(){
    cout << "Would you like to create another box? (Y/n)" << endl;
    getline(cin, answer);
    if(answer.length() == 1){
        myChar = answer[0];
        if(myChar == 'y' || myChar == 'Y'){
        vector<string> printContents();
        randomize();
    }
    }

}

void BoxOfProduce::removeStuff()
{
    cout << "Of your three bundles, what would like to remove?" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    vector<string>::iterator result = find(randomResult.begin(),  randomResult.end(), answer);
    if(answer == "Tomato" || answer == "tomato" || answer == "broccoli" || answer == "Broccoli" || answer == "kiwi" || answer == "Kiwi" || answer == "kale" || answer == "Kale" || answer == "tomatillo" || answer == "Tomatillo"){
        randomResult.erase(result);
        bundles[3] = randomResult;
        addStuff();
    }else{
        cout << "That is not a choice!" << endl;
    }
}

void BoxOfProduce::addStuff()
{
    cout << "Now that we have removed a bundle, what would you like to swap that out for: Tomato, Broccoli, Kiwi, Kale, or Tomatillo?" << endl;
    getline(cin, answer);
    if(answer == "Tomato" || answer == "tomato" || answer == "broccoli" || answer == "Broccoli" || answer == "kiwi" || answer == "Kiwi" || answer == "kale" || answer == "Kale" || answer == "tomatillo" || answer == "Tomatillo"){
        randomResult.push_back(answer);
        bundles[3] = randomResult;
        printContents(bundles);
    }else{
        cout << "Sorry, you can't add that." << endl;
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef BOXOFPRODUCE_H
#define BOXOFPRODUCE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class BoxOfProduce
{
    public:
        BoxOfProduce();
        string getBundles();
        void setBundles(string b);
        vector<string> randomize();
        string bundleOfFruit();
        vector<string> printContents(vector<string> bundles[3]);
        string random;
        void createBox();
        void removeStuff();
        void addStuff();

    private:
        vector<string> bundles[3];
        vector<string> choices[5];
        char myChar;
        string answer = "";
        vector<string> randomResult;
};

#endif // BOXOFPRODUCE_H
```

This is still very much a work in progress, so please go easy on me.

Comment: Beyond the problems answers will likely list, `BoxOfProduce::printContents` is lying to its caller, as it has no return value, but claims it does. And `BoxOfProduce::createBox()`, short of gathering an input, makes little sense, as the code in the if-block declares a useless function `printContents` (it doesn't call the member you think it may), then invokes `randomize()`, which creates a local vector, and returns it to the caller, which ignores it. The best advice to these and other issues I can give is to *turn **up** your compiler warnings to pedantic levels*, and *fix* what is flagged.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing out of bounds, e.g.

```
bundles[3] = randomResult;
```

as you have the declaration

```
vector<string> bundles[3]; // 3 elements, last one is indexed by 2
```

and in C or C++ the indexing starts from 0, so the last element of the array `bundles` should be `bundles[2]`.

In any case, are you sure you need an array of vector of strings? It seems a bit odd.

Comment: How many elements?  How many arrays?  How many vector<strings>?  What does vector<string> x[3] declare/define?

Comment: @vsoftco I updated the code to include the instructions for my program.